# Ant regex task to find unescaped percent signs

Tags: regex, ant

I need to locate unescaped percent signs in a file using an Ant task.  Normally I would use a negative look-around, but this doesn't seem to be fully supported in Ant.  Is this correct?

If so, what's the best way to capture these occurrences?

Some examples:
%m - would match
%d - would match
% - would match

\%m - would not match
\%d - would not match
\% - would not match

Comment: Would you need to be able to handle cases like `\\%m`?

Comment: Good question.  No, we shouldn't expect to see the escaped slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex support in Ant is generally plugin-dependent, so if you're using, for example, `java.util.regex`, then you should have support for negative lookbehind assertions. Assuming you don't have the ability to *any* lookaround assertions, though, the best you can do is

```
([^\\]|^)(%)
```

*Corrected expression courtesy of @TimPietzcker.*

Comment: Go with @TimPietzcker's answer. His catches a `%` at the beginning of the file as well.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Yes, I was commenting so :-) and I voted you up.

Comment: On the other hand, you're right about the Java plugin being able to handle lookarounds. So your answer might be the better one after all :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Er, the guilt, the guilt! Unfortunately I can't delete an accepted answer. But I'm sending some karma your way ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
([^\\]|^)%[md]?
```

would match a non-backslash character (or the position at the start of the string) in group number 1; so it will usually match one character more than you actually want to match, but at least you can do the match without lookaround assertions at your disposal.